# Does 'command' in Google Closure have the prototype?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

I am using Google Closure and am trying to do something like below:

```
abc.edf.commands.showToast = function() {
    abc.edf.commands.showToast.test(); // this works fine
    this.test2(); // this will throw an error like:   
    // exception_logger.js:88 TypeError: this.test2 is not a function
};

abc.edf.commands.showToast.test = function() {
    console.log('test');
};

abc.edf.commands.showToast.prototype.test2 = function() {
    console.log('test2');
};
```

I think every object in JavaScript has 'prototype'. So is it because 'command' is not an object? Or I missed something else? Thanks :)

Comment: Probably `this` doesn't refer to an instance of `abc.edf.commands.showToast`. You need to call the function with `new` for that to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Felix Kling commented you need to use `new` to create an object in order to use the `test2` prototype function.  Here is an example:

```
goog.provide('abc.edf.commands.showToast');

/** @constructor */
abc.edf.commands.showToast = function() {};

abc.edf.commands.showToast.test = function() {
    console.log('test');
};

abc.edf.commands.showToast.prototype.test2 = function() {
    console.log('test2');
};

abc.edf.commands.showToast.test(); // static class method
var foo = new abc.edf.commands.showToast();
foo.test2(); // instance method
```

You can try entering that code in the [online closure compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home).  Here is what it compiles to using simple compile:

```
var abc={edf:{}};
abc.edf.commands={};
abc.edf.commands.showToast=function(){};
abc.edf.commands.showToast.test=function(){console.log("test")};
abc.edf.commands.showToast.prototype.test2=function(){console.log("test2")};
abc.edf.commands.showToast.test();
var foo=new abc.edf.commands.showToast;
foo.test2();
```

Here is what it compiles to using advanced compile:

```
console.log("test");
console.log("test2");
```

To test, I saved the compiled code to a file "showToast.js" and made a simple html page that loads it:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <p>ShowToast Test</p>
  <script src="showToast.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```